# Creating duplicate Wordpress site for development reasons

Tags: development-strategy

How can I create a duplicate site in Wordpress running under a subdomain for development reasons, in plesk panel? Do I have to do anything for search engines to crawl of the second site?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Answer (score 1):

Three steps:

1. Create subdomain
2. Copy files - Update wp-config.php
3. Copy DB. Edit site_url and home fields in wp_options.

You should definitely add a no crawl in robots.txt [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197979/how-to-prevent-staging-to-be-indexed-in-search-engines) is another SO question that describes how to do that.